# How to Properly Build Classes that Reference one another? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm working on a procedural game level builder base on a recursive constructor. Each new Door object calls the constructor for a Room object beyond it, which in turn calls new Door constructors for its walls until the limit of rooms is reached. For proper traversal, I need my rooms to know what a Door is and my Doors to have pointers to the Rooms they go to/from, but the compiler doesn't seem to like it. At first I had my #includes daisy chained down ( >> means #include here):

randDungeon.cpp >> door.cpp >> door.h >> room.cpp >> room.h >> Library.cpp >> Library.h

but I get an error when I try to compile, with the message that, essentially, room.cpp doesn't know what a Door object is. If I reverse room and door in the flow above, I get the opposite error - my Rooms know what their Doors are, but the Doors no longer understand Room.

What's the correct organization of classes such that the non-inheritant classes Door and Room can talk to one another?

Comment: I hope you're not `#include` ing .cpp files...

Comment: I've never been told not to and the compiler doesn't complain. May I ask why?

Comment: @redkat85: Because that's not the C++ compilation model.

Answer (score 3):

All `#include` does is copy&paste the file contents into the base file (randDungeon.cpp). This makes your .h files mostly useless and, as you've discovered, makes using classes difficult

What you need to do is:

- Stop `#include`ing *.cpp files
- `#include` the relevant declarations (*.h) in files needed (.cpp and .h files), or use forward declarations of the classes (preferred)
- Look up how to compile with multiple files, as you're likely to be currently just compiling randDungeon.cpp